# Firebase - How to send email verification from onCreate cloud function listener?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to create a cloud function that will listen for when users are created, and then send an email verification to the user that was created.

I have this code:

```
export const verifyEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

});
```

The problem I have here is that `user` gives me no way of accessing `sendEmailVerification`. The only way of accessing that function is via the `currentUser`, but since this happens in a cloud function reaction to `onCreate` there is no current user.

I need to somehow get a `firebase.User` instance instead of a `firebase.UserRecord`, as the `onCreate` gives me.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get the client-side user from the server, nor is there a way to send verification emails through the Admin SDK.

You will either have to trigger the email from the app itself, or send your own verification email. In the latter case, you can still use the existing verification service, by [generating the correct email verification link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links#generate_email_verification_link).

Also see [How to send email verification after user creation with Firebase Cloud functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42872594/how-to-send-email-verification-after-user-creation-with-firebase-cloud-functions), which I'll actually mark your question as a duplicate of.

Comment: Is there any reason as to why the Admin SDK can't do this? Seems like a missing feature..

Comment: It never hurts to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). :)